# How to put conditional formatting in selected cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Conditional Formatting Condition:If selected cell("cel7") is not blank then put Black fill on it.
How can i modify my current code in such away that conditional formatting condition is used in cel7.
I tried to use xlnoblankscondition but i could not find any VBA examples of it on web.
P.S:As i have written all cel7 cell as C1,every condition will be true ie NOT BLANK.

```
x = ws.Range("A4").Value
y = ws.Range("A5").Value
ocol = 4
Set cel = Range("E6")
Set cel7 = cel.Offset(2, 0)
For m = 1 To x
For o = 1 To y
        cel7.Value = "C1"
         cel7.Select
            With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        Set cel7 = cel7.Offset(4, 0)
        Next
Set cel = cel.Offset(0, ocol)
Set cel7 = cel7.Offset(0, ocol)
Next
```

Comment: *BLACK FILL WITH WHITE TEXT

Comment: maybe `if cel7.value <> "" then cel7.interior.color=vbblack else cel7.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 end if`

Comment: It may work but i need it in such a way that if i delete any cel7 cells, then conditional formatting disappears(EMPTY) & If i write any text in cel7 cells then conditional formatting reappears( BLACK FILL WITH WHITE TEXT).I think "if" condition will not work in this case.So i need Conditional Formatting only.

Comment: maybe put this formula in the Conditional Formatting `=NOT(ISBLANK(C7))` ---> this is assuming that your "cel7" variable is actually cell C7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry as I'm still not clear on what you mean.

Anyway, I'm guessing that you want to coding the Conditional Formatting, just like when you do it manually.

I find the code below after I macro recording my manual step in Conditional Formatting.
I think the code in your condition maybe like this :

```
Sub test()
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    cel7.Select
    cf = cel7.Address(0, 0)

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=NOT(ISBLANK(" & cf & "))"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

I try the code above by having cel7 variable refer to cell D10.
After I run the code, if I type something in cell D10, D10 fill black with white font.
If I clear the content of D10, D10 back to normal (no fill).

Also I try by having cel7 variable to a range D2 to D10.
If I type on any cell within D2:D10, the cell fill black with white font.
If I clear it, the cell back to normal.

But once again, maybe that's not what you want to achieve.

If I'm not mistaken read your code, it seems that your cel7 formatting is a non-contagious row. So please try your o loop like this one :

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete 'put this line before m loop
For m = 1 To x
    For o = 1 To y
        Cel7.Select
        cf = Cel7.Address(0, 0)

        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=NOT(ISBLANK(" & cf & "))"

        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

        Set Cel7 = Cel7.Offset(4, 0)
    Next o
```

Comment: Exactly,Its just like when we do manually.Above code in not working when i tried to put it in my code.How can i put yours code into mine ?

Comment: @PramodPandit, please have a look to the addition code on my post.

Comment: Works as expected !! Thanks.

Comment: 1 last question,How is cf defined As Long,As range ie `Dim cf As ......` ? Also what does cf = cel7.Address(0, 0) do.Can you just tell it in brief..

Comment: Very sorry to be honest I don't know how to defined cf as exactly what, because I never define the variable when write a code, except I copy paste a code from the internet which already has the dim there. But I think you can try define cf as string. `range.address(0,0)` will give you the column letter and the row number.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below I took out your Selection of `Cel7`. You can address the range directly.  I also added variable declarations. Omitting them causes more work than it saves. For the rest of it, the cell color is applied if the cell is found not to be `Empty`.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cel As Range, Cel7 As Range
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim oCol As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim m As Long, o As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    x = Ws.Range("A4").Value
    y = Ws.Range("A5").Value
    oCol = 4

    Set Cel = Ws.Range("E6")
    Set Cel7 = Cel.Offset(2, 0)
    For m = 1 To x
        For o = 1 To y
            With Cel7
                Tmp = "C1"          ' avoid read/write to  sheet multiple times
                .Value = Tmp
                If IsEmpty(Tmp) Then
                    .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                Else
                    .Interior.Color = vbBlack
                End If

                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            Set Cel7 = Cel7.Offset(4, 0)
        Next o
        Set Cel = Cel.Offset(0, oCol)
        Set Cel7 = Cel7.Offset(0, oCol)
    Next m
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it..But i want it like Manual cell formatting.Example:If Cell is empty then nothing happens,If i put something in cell then Cell Formatting (Black fill with white text) appears. I guess .FormatConditions  is a way to do it !

Comment: To make it more clear,After running your Macro,If i delete the the C1 from the sheet the formatting (Black fill with white text) must disappear and if i again type anything on that cell the formatting should re-appear just like doing manually in excel : cell formatting->New rule

Comment: I have modified my answer to show how to make the cell black or colorless. In this code the cell will always be given the value of "C1". Therefore it can't be blank. The question is how you want to use the code. Perhaps you want to incorporate it in an event procedure. Say, cell C18 changes and you want to color or not color it. You could treat all cells in column C that way or some of the cell is column C. Your present question is different. It doesn't allow for such an application. You asked how to do it. Here is the answer. Your next question might be how to apply this answer.

Comment: My recommendation is to use either VBA **or** Conditional Formatting. The problem you depict seems to require CF. If so, forget about VBA. Doing the same thing using VBA has advantages. It's much easier to maintain and doesn't need repair. The drawback is that you need to know VBA. More specifically, you need to deploy Change event procedures in your project. Action happens when a cell is changed. You want the cell's color to change. Nothing sinister there, but it can't be done with the code you already have or ask about here.